# How can I store instances of TabItem and load the instances on Application start (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, serialization, tabitem

I'm storing the instances of TabItem by retrieving the Selected Tab Item from the TabControl's "SelectedItem" property into a Dictionary of Type (String, TabItem) on Button click 1 by 1.

After few clicks I have a Dictionary containing lots of TabItems. Now I would like to store this entire dictionary permanently such that I can load it on application start. Any suggestions on how and where I can store the instances? I know file is an option but is there any other alternative?

I tried serializing the dictionary and store it in a file but it gives me error stating TabItem is not serializable.

Comment: Why are you trying to store the TabItems?

Comment: The application I'm working on is not made by me and is written really bad. It uses custom implementation of "TabControl" which it calls "NTabControlViewModel" and similarly the individual "TabItems" are "NTabPageViewModel". 

Now these TabControls have "SelectedItem" property which surprisingly stores "TabItem" instead of "NTabPageViewModel".  I cannot convert "NTabPageViewModel" to "TabItem". 

Instead I can retrieve the currently selected tab and store it and later use it to set the tab manualy. Hence I want to store the tabs permanently as "TabItem" somewhere instead of "NTabPageViewModel"